# Using repl.bat to find and replace text over multiple lines

Tags: batch-file, replace

I have the following code in a file defines.h:

```
#ifdef ANDROID
#define GAME_VERSION (3000)
#else
#define GAME_VERSION (3020)
#endif
```

I can use this command to replace all instances of the game version number using this:

```
type "defines.h"|repl "(#define GAME_VERSION \().*?(\))" "$1%ANDROID_VERSION_NAME_WHOLE%$2" >"defines_new.h"
```

I am struggling to come up with a call that would e.g. just replace the one within the #ifdef ANDROID block. Does anyone have any ideas please?

Thanks,
Chris.

Comment: REPL.BAT has been retired. You should switch to using his big brother - [JREPL.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044)

Comment: Thanks @dbenham, should this in theory support all the stuff that repl.bat supported and more?

Comment: Absolutely - significantly more.

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question here, hopefully this helps someone else.

```
type "defines.h"|repl "(#ifdef ANDROID\s*#define GAME_VERSION \().*?(\))" "$13400$2" m >"defines_new.h"
```

Comment: Crucial parts here were the m option to use multiple lines and the \s* part